# Laravel Sail uses Apache or Nginx?

Tags: laravel

I use docker, installed Laravel 9 via Sail.
I'm wondering it uses Apache or Nginx?
Which file/line set the public folder as document root?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the official repo for Laravel sail
https://github.com/laravel/sail

- not apache or nginx it's just the built-in PHP server run by `php artisan server` command

check this file

https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/supervisord.conf#L8

I hope it's helpful